# Cooked chicken on bone - how to refrigerate and reheat some

Tags: food-safety, chicken, reheating

I've made a cooked chicken on the bone (Coq Au Vin), however some guests couldn't attend, so two Chicken legs are left over.

I'm planning to cool then refrigerate these and then re-heat in a pan tomorrow (we have no microwave).

As long as I get it piping when I reheat it is it ok food safety-wise or should I be doing things differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Food safety guidelines suggest that when reheating food you should heat to 165 degrees F to kill any bacteria which might have been tempted by your food between when you cooked it and when you eat it again.  As long as you do this and eat your food within 4 days, you should be fine.